# jQuery show/hide div with dropdown more levels

Tags: jquery, forms

I am searching now for 2 days for an solution to show/hide divs including dropdowns depending on the selected value.

Thats my attempt so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#auswahl_lkw").hide();
$("#auswahl_raupen").hide();
$("#auswahl_teleskopstapler").hide();
$("#auswahl_bagger").hide();
$("#auswahl_gelenk_antrieb").hide();
$("#auswahl_gelenk_elektro").hide();
$("#auswahl_gelenk_diesel").hide();
 $("#auswahl_scheren_antrieb").hide();
$("#auswahl_scheren_elektro").hide();
$("#auswahl_scheren_diesel").hide();

$("#auswahl_hebebuehnen").change(function() {
    if ($("#auswahl_hebebuehnen").val() == "LKW-Hebebühnen") {
        $("#auswahl_lkw").show();

    }
    else {
        $("#auswahl_lkw").hide();

    }

    if ($("#auswahl_hebebuehnen").val() == "Gelenkteleskopbühnen") {
        $("#auswahl_gelenk_antrieb").show();

    }
    else {
        $("#auswahl_gelenk_antrieb").hide();

    }


    if ($("#auswahl_hebebuehnen").val() == "Raupenhebebühnen") {
        $("#auswahl_raupen").show();

    }
    else {
        $("#auswahl_raupen").hide();

    }

    if ($("#auswahl_hebebuehnen").val() == "Scherenhebebühnen") {
        $("#auswahl_scheren_antrieb").show();

    }
    else {
        $("#auswahl_scheren_antrieb").hide();

    }

    if ($("#auswahl_hebebuehnen").val() == "Teleskopstapler") {
        $("#auswahl_teleskopstapler").show();

    }
    else {
        $("#auswahl_teleskopstapler").hide();

    }

    if ($("#auswahl_hebebuehnen").val() == "Bagger") {
        $("#auswahl_bagger").show();

    }
    else {
        $("#auswahl_bagger").hide();

    }
});    
});
```

This code works pretty nice for the 1. Level, but for:

```
    if ($("#auswahl_hebebuehnen").val() == "Gelenkteleskopbühnen") {
        $("#auswahl_gelenk_antrieb").show();

    }
    else {
        $("#auswahl_gelenk_antrieb").hide();

    }
```

is displayed a dropdown for #auswahl_gelenk_antrieb, where you can choose 2 options, depending on that options, should be displayed another div #auswahl_scheren_elektro or #auswahl_scheren_diesel below.

The HTML Code is from Contact form 7 Plugin Wordpress and it should be ok, because the code works good for the 1. level.

I hope someone can give me a useful hint.

ty

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please could you edit your question and add all the relevant code that consistently reproduces the problem? The `HTML` and `CSS` that this JavaScript operates on is missing.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#auswahl_lkw").hide();
$("#auswahl_raupen").hide();
$("#auswahl_teleskopstapler").hide();
$("#auswahl_bagger").hide();
$("#auswahl_gelenk_antrieb").hide();
$("#auswahl_gelenk_elektro").hide();
$("#auswahl_gelenk_diesel").hide();
 $("#auswahl_scheren_antrieb").hide();
$("#auswahl_scheren_elektro").hide();
$("#auswahl_scheren_diesel").hide();
```

istead of this^

```
$('.hidden_divs').hide();// give all divs a common class. and give them different ids `//according to the value of the select box;`  


//$("#auswahl_hebebuehnen") << its a select box i think

$("#auswahl_hebebuehnen").change(function() {
$('.hidden_divs').hide();
$('#'+$(this).val()).show();
});
```

html example

```
<div class="hidden_divs" id="LKW-Hebebühnen"></div>
<div class="hidden_divs" id="Gelenkteleskopbühnen"></div>
<div class="hidden_divs" id="Raupenhebebühnen"></div>
```

even its dynamic, generating ids and option values are not complicated...